# Ubuntu 20.04 - No WiFi adapter found

Tags: drivers, wireless, intel, msi

I built my first PC today, and installed Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS on it. Ubuntu is the only OS on the machine. The build is as follows

```
MSI Z590 Pro Wifi Motherboard
Intel i7-11700K CPU
G.SKILL Ripjaws V Series 32GB (2x16GB) DDR4 3200 RAM
Corsair CX-F CX550F 550W PSU
Samsung 970 EVO PLUS M.2 2280 1TB PCIE 3.0 x4 NVMe SSD
be Quiet dark rock slim CPU Cooler
```

The motherboard has wifi & bluetooth built in. (WiFi card is Intel AX210 160MHz) The bluetooth is working fine but the WiFi is not: I get the error "No WiFi Adapter Found".

Kernel version is:
`5.11.0-37-generic`

The output from `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```bsh
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0024]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The output from `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

```bsh
[    1.714886] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.719096] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    1.719151] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[    1.720099] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    1.786073] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    1.938848] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x324cd670
[    2.188073] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[    2.188077] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    2.188081] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 1
[    2.392032] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware didnt ACK the reset - continue anyway
[    2.404087] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

That spits out `Failed to run INIT ucode: -110`, but when I look up that error, none of the fixes work for me. I'm currently connected through USB Tether to my iPhone, and have tried running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` but it doesn't fix it. I also tried re-installing Ubuntu, but to no avail.

I have no idea what else to try. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the kernel version?

Comment: 5.11.0-37-generic, edited question to add that as well @Pilot6

Comment: See https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212371

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the solution is to delete `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm` file.

Source https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212371

Beware that the file will appear in case `linux-firmware` package gets an update. If the issue won't be fixed at that time, Wi-Fi will stop working again.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. Will accept this answer in 6 minutes when I'm able to