# Install Intel Wireless Drivers on GP66 Leopard laptop running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, intel

My device can't found any wifi drivers as I turned to Ubuntu 20.04 on my GP66 Leopard with the following devices:

```
anto@anto-GP66-Leopard-11UH:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Rivet Networks Device [1a56:1674]
    Kernel modules: wl
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I tried to do the following:

## first attempt

1. Add `restricted` component repository

   ```
    sudo add-apt-repository restricted
   ```
2. Update packages list

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Confirm that you have kernel headers installed and updated

   ```
    sudo apt-get install linux-generic
   ```
4. Then install it again

   ```
    sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
   ```

## Second attempt

1. Go to the Intel Linux Driver Downloads.
2. Download the appropriate driver for my card. The one that comes with the Framework laptop is the Wi-Fi 6 AX210. Don’t mind that it is lacking the E.
3. Download and extract the files in the tarball to my downloads folder or other location.
4. Open my terminal and cd into the directory containing the files you just extracted.
5. Run this command. Replaced XX with the version number of my driver (or just use tab autofill): `sudo cp iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-XX.gcode /lib/firmware`
6. Reboot my laptop.

None of them worked.

I don't know if it's related but this brand new machine freeze from time to time. I suspect it is rather because of the Intel Graphics driver...

## delete file

I deleted /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm file but it still don't recognize my drivers

## kernel version

```
anto@anto-GP66-Leopard-11UH:/lib/firmware$ uname -a
Linux anto-GP66-Leopard-11UH 5.11.0-40-generic #44~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 26 18:07:44 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## kernel ring buffer

```
nto@anto-GP66-Leopard-11UH:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
...
...
...   
[ 1462.669931]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
[ 1464.674559] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg overlay bnep ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mc usbhid ecdh_generic ecc snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp input_leds snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_tcc_cooling snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_powerclamp iwlmvm snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211
[ 1464.674576]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
[ 1466.679202] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg overlay bnep ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mc usbhid ecdh_generic ecc snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp input_leds snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_tcc_cooling snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_powerclamp iwlmvm snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211
[ 1466.679219]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
[ 1468.683857] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg overlay bnep ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mc usbhid ecdh_generic ecc snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp input_leds snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_tcc_cooling snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_powerclamp iwlmvm snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211
[ 1468.683873]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
[ 1470.688497] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg overlay bnep ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mc usbhid ecdh_generic ecc snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp input_leds snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_tcc_cooling snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_powerclamp iwlmvm snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211
[ 1470.688514]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
[ 1472.693132] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg overlay bnep ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mc usbhid ecdh_generic ecc snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp input_leds snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_tcc_cooling snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_powerclamp iwlmvm snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211
[ 1472.693149]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
[ 1474.697775] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg overlay bnep ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mc usbhid ecdh_generic ecc snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp input_leds snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_tcc_cooling snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_powerclamp iwlmvm snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211
[ 1474.697792]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
[ 1476.702437] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg overlay bnep ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mc usbhid ecdh_generic ecc snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp input_leds snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_tcc_cooling snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_powerclamp iwlmvm snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211
[ 1476.702454]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
[ 1478.707078] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg overlay bnep ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mc usbhid ecdh_generic ecc snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp input_leds snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_tcc_cooling snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_powerclamp iwlmvm snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211
[ 1478.707095]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
[ 1480.711724] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg overlay bnep ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mc usbhid ecdh_generic ecc snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp input_leds snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_tcc_cooling snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_powerclamp iwlmvm snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211
[ 1480.711741]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
[ 1482.716362] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg overlay bnep ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mc usbhid ecdh_generic ecc snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp input_leds snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_tcc_cooling snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_powerclamp iwlmvm snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211
[ 1482.716379]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
[ 1484.721019] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg overlay bnep ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mc usbhid ecdh_generic ecc snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp input_leds snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_tcc_cooling snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_powerclamp iwlmvm snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211
[ 1484.721036]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
[ 1486.725665] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg overlay bnep ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mc usbhid ecdh_generic ecc snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp input_leds snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_tcc_cooling snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_powerclamp iwlmvm snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211
[ 1486.725682]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
[ 1488.730299] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg overlay bnep ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mc usbhid ecdh_generic ecc snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp input_leds snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_tcc_cooling snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_powerclamp iwlmvm snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211
[ 1488.730315]  snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel coretemp wl(PO) libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nouveau nls_iso8859_1 kvm_intel i915 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel mei_hdcp drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd iwlwifi snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cryptd ttm intel_cstate snd_seq drm_kms_helper cfg80211 msi_wmi snd_seq_device snd_timer cec wmi_bmof sparse_keymap efi_pstore ee1004 rc_core processor_thermal_device snd processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit mei_me processor_thermal_mbox fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch syscopyarea soundcore processor_thermal_rapl mei sysfillrect intel_pmt_telemetry intel_pmt_class sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad soc_button_array acpi_tad joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 - No WiFi adapter found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369671/ubuntu-20-04-no-wifi-adapter-found)

Comment: Thanks @ChanganAuto unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica All your actions were wrong. 1) Installing `linux-generic` 2) Installing Broadcom drivers 3)Deleting firmware.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for pointing that out I have no idea of how to handle this WiFi issue. Should I reinstall Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Install 20.04.3 and if you still have a problem ask a question with output of `dmesg | grep iwl`. And is it a dual boot?

Comment: Which kernel are you using? Please post the output of `uname -a`.

Comment: Just added it @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica Check if the first part of my answer works.

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `dmesg | grep iwl` There might be an issue with the firmware version being higher than what the kernel will load

Comment: Sure @Jeremy31 I just shared it

Answer (score 0):

According to [Linux Hardware](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:8086-2725-1a56-1674) this network card is supported by kernel driver 5.12 or above.

You can install kernel 5.13 on Ubuntu 20.04 with

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge
```

and reboot.

---

Alternatively,
You can use the [mainline](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline/) tool to update the kernel to 5.12 or a later version.
There is a PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

[image: mainline]

<sup>Image source: Project README</sup>

Here you can install a kernel like 5.13 or 5.14 and reboot (*please note that the mainline kernels are not as stable as the default kernels, and may have other issues*).

Comment: Why go through that effort when you can install the 5.13 on Ubuntu 20.04 with `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge`

Comment: @Jeremy31 DId not know that! Thank you.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Nah, thanks but ... it didn't worked ...