# wifi not working (Intel AX210) on my z590 setup? (Trying to install 20.04.3 with kernel 5.11.0)

Tags: 20.04, system-installation

As above.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.3 but no network is detected even the wifi controller.

I was initially getting a blank screen so I decided to boot into windows and copy the latest LTS iso to USB using Rufus.

The kernel version was acquired using "uname -a" after booting into the installer.

Thanks

Comment: As it is currently written, your question is unclear. Please provide enough details, so that one can find an adequate answer.

Comment: Edited. Hope this is clearer

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1369672/1222991) might give you what you need. Note that you may need to first install the OS.

Comment: Please open a terminal and tell us if the driver module loaded: `lsmod | grep iwlwifi` Are there any clues in the message log? `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Please edit your question to show the results.