# wlo1 for Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 missing

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I have installed Ubuntu (Mate) **20.04.3 LTS** on a Dell Precision 7760 with an **Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210** module. But right from the beginning the Wi-Fi does seem to work (even during the installation):

[image: No "Wi-Fi Networks" shown.]

When I run `sudo nmcli device`, I get:

```
DEVICE     TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
enp0s31f6  ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
lo         loopback  unmanaged  --
```

So apparently the `wlo1` or its equivalent is missing.

According to [wireless.wiki.kernel.org](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi) the **6E AX210** is supported from Kernel version 5.10 on. I am running **5.11.0-46-generic**, so this should be fine, right?

Following [this guide by Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/de-de/000130686/anleitung-zum-troubleshooting-von-wireless-netzwerkproblemen-in-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc) I ran `sudo lshw -c network` and got:

```
 *-network                 
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:93:00.0
   version: 1a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
   resources: irq:17 memory:b1200000-b1203fff
```

I also ran `lspci` and got:

```
93:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4020]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

For both these cases the Dell guide suggestes to "reinstall the device drivers". But this confuses me. I thought the drivers were embedded in the Kernel. So how am I supposed to "reinstall" them?

### Update

OK, sorry for not having found this before. Turns out my issue is a duplicate of
[Intel Wifi 5 AX210 - WiFi not working after Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-5-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update) and
[Ubuntu 20.04 - No WiFi adapter found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369671/ubuntu-20-04-no-wifi-adapter-found/1369672#1369672)

I.e. I am suffering from this bug:
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212371

Renaming this file fixed it for me!

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm  /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.bak
```

Comment: Search here for "AX210" and you'll find your answer :-)

Comment: Oh damn, how could I not have found this! Thanks for the hint. ;-)